# Nestjs + Socket.io - doesn't work on custom port after deploy on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, socket.io, nestjs

I am facing an issue with my backend app on Nest.js and Socket.io after deploying on Heroku (on localhost all works), then I try to set a custom port for WebSockets from @WebSocketGateway() decorator.

When I set empty decorator like that, all is working:

> @WebSocketGateway()
> [image]
> [image]

But when I set this decorator with some params (like port), and I can't connect to my ws endpoint.
[image]
[image]

Did someone face a similar problem?

I created codesandbox with this code - https://codesandbox.io/s/nest-socket-io-custom-options-forked-vgx238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku doesn't expose every port, just the port assigned to the `PORT` env variable which is what your application should be running on. There's no way to use a custom port other than the given `process.env.PORT`

Comment: Hi Jay!
Thanks for your answer!

If I understood correctly.
So, I tried changing it to this:
For rest API:
const PORT = Number(process.env.PORT);
await app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started at ${PORT}`));

For ws server:
@WebSocketGateway(Number(process.env.PORT))

My Heroku "Config Vars": PORT => 3000


I checked it on localhost - everything works there.
But when I try to do it on Heroku, only my rest API works :(

Did I do everything right?

Comment: I updated codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/nest-socket-io-custom-options-forked-vgx238?file=/src/main.ts

Comment: You shouldn't set `PORT` yourself. My answer boils down to "On Heroku it's not possible to use two different ports." Everything has to be on the _same_ port.

Comment: Got it, that explains a lot. Thanks a lot for your help!